# Select records from current month

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with a *varchar* field called **slldate**. This field contains dates in this format:
2010-08-30
(YYYY-MM-DD)

Now I would like to select the records containing the current month using a mysql query.

Anyone?

Answer (score 7):

as you used a char field instead a date field, you have to cast the value and then use the normal date functions. like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(CAST(slidate as date)) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(CAST(slidate as date)) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: Thanks, can I convert the char field into a date field without loosing the records? and how would the select statement look like if i convert the field to a date field?

Comment: That would actually select previous years too, not sure if that's preferred.

Comment: Wesley van Opdorp, would it help by adding YEAR(NOW())

Comment: you just need to add the year as well, updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: @dreni: if you really have only valid dates in it, it should work. copy the table first and try it out.

Comment: ...but if you try this you won't be able to sue any indexes!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MONTH(slldate) = date('m') AND YEAR(slldate) = date('Y');

Comment: Rufinus, would this work if i convert the varchar field to a date field?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a table with a varchar field called slldate. This field contains dates

Then you should change it to a date field. You (should) know it's the right thing to do.

The method below will work with your varchar strings - but can be simplified somewhat for dates.

Note that since your date strings are already big-endian, you don't need to cast them and loose the benefit of index optinmisation:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM yourtable
 WHERE slldate >= CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-', NOW()),'01')
 AND slldate < CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-', NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '01')
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE YEAR(`savedate`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`savedate`) = MONTH(CURDATE())